# Android Wear device (Samsung Gear Live) not recognized on Mac (Maverick)

Tags: android, wear-os, samsung-galaxy-gear

I'm trying to follow https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html to develop a Wear app. I have a Samsung Gear Live, a Nexus 4 and a Macbook Pro. The Mac detects the Nexus 4 but not the Gear Live (using the same cable). adb doesn't show the Gear Live (but the watch shows a charging icon).

I'm following all the steps in the link above regarding adding a physical device (debugging is enabled in the Android Wear app and the app syncs with the clock perfectly), but when the watch is connected nothing happens (no message on the devices, no device on adb list).

I have seen several threads here but they all refer to Windows and how to install the drivers. Since there are no Mac drivers this should be working out of the box but no luck.

Any google dev knows what the problem might be?

Best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the developer features where completly disabled on this commercial (non-Google IO) watch.

You must enable ADB in the watch by enabling the [hidden developer settings](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/07/05/how-to-android-wear-enable-debugging-take-screenshots-unlock-the-bootloader-and-root-the-lg-g-watch/).

Comment: My GoogleIO watch didn't have this enabled either. You don't have to unlock the bootloader, but the rest of the linked tutorial is helpful.

Comment: All Android devices from 4.2 onwards have the Developer Options hidden by default.

Comment: @German, although I followed the instruction on your link, the last screen (Allow Wear Debugging) didn't appear, and when I ran 'adb devices' I don't see the wear, did you see it in the list?

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to wok with a real Wear device rather than emulator. Have you paired the Wear and the Android Wear app on the phone correctly? Have you enabled bluetooth debugging on the Android Wear app on the phone? Have you enabled the developer options on the Wear (tap 7 times on Build number) and the enabled adb debugging and bluetooth debugging?

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar setup. Here is what worked for me:

Enable adb debugging in the developer options on your watch.
Enable bluetooth debugging in the developer options on your watch.
Enable bluetooth debugging in the wear app on your phone.

run in terminal:
adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub; adb connect localhost:4444

http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html

I think I also had luck with using the cradle plugged directly into the computer, but unable to confirm that now.